# Angular 5 Send Object from Angular to Express Route

Tags: angular, mean

I'd like to send user object from angular to express, but when I try to console.log in express, it return undefined. 
This is my method inside ts file :

```
  updateProfileCompany(){
    var getUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    getUser = JSON.parse(getUser)
    var id_student = getUser["id"];
    var nim        = getUser["nim"];
    var nama       = getUser["nama"];
    var email      = getUser["email"];
    var company    = this.company
    const user = {
      id         : id_student,
      nama       : nama,
      email      : email,
      nim        : nim,
      id_company : company
    }
    console.log(user.id_company); // This is work
    this.authService.updateProfileCompany(user)
    .subscribe((res:Response) => this.user = user);
  }
```

This is my express route :

```
router.put('/update', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next)=>{
    user = req.user;
    var result = [];
    console.log(user.id_company); // returns undefined
});
```

Comment: post what you see when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(user));

Comment: {"company":[],"_id":"5ad72254452996029415e49f","nama":"Muhammad Fatih Rizqon","email":"fatih@me.id","nim":"14520111003","password":"$2a$10$n1jbglV3F0RRvTkSVGFNSOrJ.y9A/7zZkVsCq.BUmmTzSg7pChykK","__v":1}

Answer (score 0):

There is no **`id_company`** in your object, i think you need **`_id`**

DEMO

```js
var user  ={"company":[],"_id":"5ad72254452996029415e49f","nama":"Muhammad Fatih Rizqon","email":"fatih@me.id","nim":"14520111003","password":"$2a$10$n1jbglV3F0RRvTkSVGFNSOrJ.y9A/7zZkVsCq.BUmmTzSg7pChykK","__v":1};
console.log(user._id);
```

Comment: It's ID user, what I want is to insert id company into my user object.

Comment: As I mentioned you are not passing it to the server

Comment: And then how to pass it?